# Java get current day from unix timestamp

Tags: java, unix-timestamp

I want to convert unix timestamp to only the current day, like the current day of the month of current day of the year, is it possible to do only using math, like *, /, or something?

Comment: Current day in which time zone, for starters?

Comment: `Instant.ofEpochSecond( 1501350790 ).atZone( ZoneId( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ).toLocalDate()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SimpleDateFormat to format your date:

```
long unixSeconds = 1372339860;
Date date = new Date(unixSeconds*1000L); // *1000 is to convert seconds to milliseconds
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"); // the format of your date
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-4")); // give a timezone reference for formating (see comment at the bottom
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

---

You can also convert it to milliseconds by multiplying the timestamp by 1000:

```
java.util.Date dateTime=new java.util.Date((long)timeStamp*1000);
```

After doing it, you can get what you want:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(dateTime);
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH); //here is what you need
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Comment: I get you, but I only want the output in the current day, if the day of the month is 29, then I only want the output 29, current day of the year is also fine, like 210 (2017-07-29)

Comment: Just updated the answer. Take a look and see if it solves you problem.

Comment: FYI, these troublesome classes are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Answer (score 2):

The short solution is something like

```
long epoch = 1501350790; // current unix time
int day = Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("dd").format(new Date(epoch * 1000L)));
```

it is possible to get this result by calculation (* and /) but there is no easy way. you can use the implementation of [java.util.GregorianCalendar](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/62df9772b849/src/share/classes/java/util/GregorianCalendar.java) as reference

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the date from a unix timestamp with `java.util.Date`
You need to multiply the timestamp with 1000, because java expects milliseconds. You can use the `cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)` function to print the day.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class MyFirstJavaProgram {
    public static void main(String []args) {
       long unixTimeStamp= System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
       java.util.Date time=new java.util.Date((long)unixTimeStamp*1000);
       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       // It's a good point better use cal because date-functions are deprecated
       cal.setTime(time);
       System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }
}
```

Any further questions please leave a comment.

Comment: Or ideally *don't* use `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` - use the far, far better `java.time.*` API...